# Descriptors as dict values

Tags: python, dictionary, descriptor

I have a dictionary-like object which store descriptors inside:

```
 class MyDict(object):
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        v = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
           return v.__get__(None, self)
        return v

class MyDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, value, attrib={}):
        self.__value = value
        self.attrib= attrib

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.__value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.__value = value
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
d = MyDict()
d['1'] = MyDescriptor("123", {"name": "val"})
print d['1']                     # prints "123"
print d['1'].attrib["name"]      # prints "val"
```

My classes don't work. Could you please help me?

Comment: It's always helpful to tell in which way your code fails. Include error messages and such things.

Comment: you could not have a method which return different values depending of what you expect (a string in the first print and a MyDescriptor in the second), nonetheless you could add a __str__ method to your MyDescriptor class

Comment: Also, this is a good watch: http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks unnecessarily complicated to solve your problem, unless there's more to it that is shown.  Why not simply do this:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(value, attrib=None):
        self.__value = value
        self.attrib = {} if attrib is None else attrib

    def __str__(self):
        return __value

d = {}
d['1'] = MyObject("123", {"name": "val"})
print d['1']                     # prints "123"
print d['1'].attrib["name"]      # prints "val"
```

As for why your code doesn't work, there are a few obvious problems.

- From your calls in various special methods of `__dict__`, it appears that `MyDict` is meant to subclass `dict`, so the definition should be:

  ```
  class MyDict(dict):
      ...
  ```
- While not incorrect, it is better practice to use `super` rather than referring to the 
  base class  directly, so `dict.__init__(self)` would become `super(MyDict, self).__init__()` and `dict.__getitem__(self, key)` becomes `super(MyDict, dict).__getitem__(key)`.
- Your call to **get** sill work, but doesn't match the method specification.  You should
  call it as `v.__get__(self, MyDict)`.  However, the way you are using it actually makes `__get__` redundant, and I think that this usage it where the main problem lies.
- In class `MyDescriptor`, [early binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651154/why-are-default-arguments-evaluated-at-definition-time-in-python) will give you unexpected results for `attrib`.  See my example above for a better way for declaring it.

I suspect that instead of a description, what you actually want is an object which looks like a string (for some definition of "looks like"), but has an attribute `attrib`.  To do this, there is no need to try to create a descriptor, which is intended for a different use case altogether.  My example above gives a class which satisfies the requirement of an object which "looks like" a string, where "looks like" means it prints a string, but here is another which may be more like what you want:

```
class MyString(str):
    def __init__(self, value, attrib=None):
        super(MyString, self).__init__(value)
        self.attrib = {} if attrib is None else attrib
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solves your use case, but in terms of achieving the results you've stated you could simply remove your `MyDict` class and use an ordinary `dict`:

```
d = {}
```

Then, add a `__str__` method to the `MyDescriptor` class returning `self.__value` and you'll achieve the results you've described.

```
>>> d['1'] = MyDescriptor("123", {"name": "val"})
>>> d['1']                     
123
>>> d['1'].attrib["name"] 
val
```