# Python: printing all nodes of tree unintentionally stores data

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, tree

I've created a general tree in python, by creating a Node object.  Each node can have either 0, 1, or 2 trees.

I'm trying to create a method to print a list of all the nodes in a tree.  The list need not be in order.  Here's my simplistic attempt:

```
def allChildren(self, l = list()):
    l.append(self)
    for child in self.children:
        l = child.allChildren(l)
    return l
```

The first time I run this method, it works correctly.  However, for some reason it is storing the previous runs.  The second time I run the method, it prints all the nodes twice.  Even if I create 2 separate trees, it still remembers the previous runs.  E.g: I create 2 trees, a and b.  If I run a.allChildren() I receive the correct result.  Then I run b.allChildren() and recieve all of a's nodes and all of b's nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
def allChildren(self, l = None):
    if(l==None):
        l = list()

    l.append(self)
    for child in self.children:
        l = child.allChildren(l)
    return l
```

And check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651154/why-are-default-arguments-evaluated-at-definition-time-in-python) for explanation.

Answer (score 5):

You have a mutable value as the default value of your function parameter `l`. In Python, this means that when you call `l.append(self)`, you are permanently modifying the default parameter.

In order to avoid this problem, set `l` to a new list every time the function is called, if no list is passed in:

```
def allChildren(self, l = None):
    if l is None:
        l = list()
    l.append(self)
    for child in self.children:
        l = child.allChildren(l)
    return l
```

This phenomenon is explained much more thoroughly in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing default parameter like l = list(), it will create list when compiling function, so it will one instance of list for all function calls. To prevent this, use None and create new list inside the function:

```
def allChildren(self, l = None):
    if not l: l = []
    l.append(self)
    for child in self.children:
        l = child.allChildren(l)
    return l
```