# Unexpected behavior while importing python Modules with Class Definitions

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-import

Consider the code in the file my_module.py:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, x=er()):
    self.x = x
```

Now, when I import this module

```
import my_module
```

I get an error,

```
name 'er is not defined
```

While I understand that my_module does not have `er` defined, but I am never creating an instance of `class A`. Therefore it is puzzling that python tries to execute the `__init__` callback when simply importing the module. Although, the `__init__` call is not fully executed as explained by the example below:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, x=5):
    self.x = x
    print ('I am here')
```

Now, when I import the module - nothing is printed and this is expected behavior.

I am puzzled why is function `er` called in the first example when I donot instantiate an object of `class A`. Any pointers to the documentation that explains this?

Comment: Anyway, `x` isn't acting as a callback here, if that's what you mean. You can just have a parameter `er`, and in `__init__` you can do `self.x = er()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in Python, default argument values are evaluated at *definition time*. See, for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651154/why-are-default-arguments-evaluated-at-definition-time-in-python), or [this notorious question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)

> The default values are evaluated at the point of function definition
>   in the defining scope, so that
>
> ```
> i = 5
>
> def f(arg=i):
>     print(arg)
>
> i = 6
> ```
>
> `f()` will print 5.
>
> **Important warning**: The default value is evaluated only once. This
>   makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a
>   list, dictionary, or instances of most classes. For example, the
>   following function accumulates the arguments passed to it on
>   subsequent calls:
>
> ```
> def f(a, L=[]):
>     L.append(a)
>     return L
>
> print(f(1))
> print(f(2))
> print(f(3))
> ```
>
> This will print
>
> ```
> [1]
> [1, 2]
> [1, 2, 3]
> ```
>
> If you don’t want the default to be shared between subsequent calls,
>   you can write the function like this instead:
>
> ```
> def f(a, L=None):
>     if L is None:
>         L = []
>     L.append(a)
>     return L
> ```