# python UUID4 in function parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
     def __init__(self, unique_id=uuid.uuid4())
```

I want every object I instantiate to have a different ID if the user doesn't specify one. When I instantiate several classes, they all have the same UUID. May I have a technical overview of what's going on here, so I may better understand Python functions and initializers?

Comment: Default parameters in Python are evaluated at function *definition* time, not function *call* time. They become part of the function object. I'm sure there's a question on SO somewhere about this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651154/why-are-default-arguments-evaluated-at-definition-time-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it makes your code cleaner, if you just add this to the method body, i.e. something like:

```
def __init__(self, unique_id=None):
    if not unique_id:
        unique_id = uuid.uuid4()
```

The more compact version of this would be:

```
def __init__(self, unique_id=None):
    unique_id = uuid.uuid4() if not unique_id else unique_id
```

This would allow you to overwrite `unique_id` if required.

Comment: This is the usual pattern for default parameters that should be evaluated at call time in Python.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your proposed code is that the default parameter is evaluated only once (when you import the module), see e.g. ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

In order to fix this, you should follow the idiom of using `None` as a flag for "not provided by user", like so:

```
def __init__(self, unique_id=None):
    if unique_id is None:
        unique_id = uuid.uuid4()
```